Use Xdebug for a multi-user environment on a remote server using VSCode and SSH
I manage a multi-user development environment on a server. There is a virtual server for each user with its corresponding domain to launch their application. Users connect to said environment (remote repository) through VSCode and SSH using a plugin. The goal is for each user to be able to debug their own application using Xdebug, but I'm having trouble with the ports.
So far I have only been able to get it to work with one user at a time. If one user is debugging and a second user starts debugging in VS Code, it shows an error saying that the port is already in use.
I have tried with DBGpProxy and followed the following tutorial in detail https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3RkGZK-UC8 but I get the same problem. When I have the proxy running and launch the debug in VSCode to register the client, it tells me that said port is already in use.
Everything runs on the same machine.
I don't know if my wish is viable.
Xdebug config:

launch.json:

Starting dbgpProxy:

Xdebug error:


What you describe as Xdebug error: (last screen shot), is really an error that the IDE gives you. It does not come from Xdebug.

seeing your dbgproxy -i 127.0.0.1:9000 -s 127.0.0.1:9005
I would create for each developer on .vscode folder located at root of the proyect this file
launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9004 (a different one by developper but not 9003 neither 9005),
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/aplica/wwwsec-64102": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "proxy": {
                "name": "Attach to Chrome",
                "enable": true,
                "port": 9000,
                "host": "127.0.0.1",
                "key": "dev_own_key"
                }
        }   
    ]
}


If the DBGp Proxy listens on port 9005, then the IDE cannot listen on the same port on that same host. That's why you get the error.
Your solution would likely be to change the configuration to use a different port for each developer. VS Code supports setting the port to 0 to pick a random one, which should also work. When VS Code registers itself with the proxy, it will tell it where it can find it's listening port.
Xdebug's configuration should use the DBGp proxy's server port number, and not the client port number. You currently have xdebug.client_port=9005, and this correctly matches the -s flag on your proxy command line.
There is another configuration issue:

In VS Code's proxy setting, you need to set the proxy.port setting to the same port as you specified with the -i flag when you start the proxy The default for this is 9001, which is what I recommend you use in the dbgpProxy invocation.


Remember that the workflow is as follows:

Start proxy — without any arguments, -i (VS Code listening port) is localhost:9001 and -s (Xdebug listening port) is localhost:9003.
You start the connection on the IDE. VS Code will connect to proxy.port (default 9001) and tell the proxy where it can find the IDE for user dev_alex (set through proxy.key). Normally it tells the proxy that is the value of port. You should therefore set to 0 to make it random per user.
When Xdebug starts, it will connect by default to port 9003 (which matches the default of -s in the proxy) and sends through its IDE key. Which you can configure in 90-xdebug.ini with the xdebug.ide_key setting. (Alternatively you can use a browser extension too).
The proxy sees whether there is an IDE registered for the IDE key (dev_alex) and then forwards the request to the port number that the IDE (VS Code) says where it is listening. (With port set to 0, that is a random port).
Then the debugging session is initialised and can work normally.


I would recommend you leave all the port settings for Xdebug, the DBGp proxy, and VS Code's proxy.port to its defaults, and set VS Code's port to 0.

The problem is that I can't register the IDE key with VSCode in the proxy. I can't have the proxy server occupying ports 9001 and 9003 and then use the same ports in VSCode to do the IDE key registration.
